# Visual Studio Console App (.exe) hangs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I have an infinite do while loop written in C# that prints time, indefinitely.
It has system threading wait for 10 seconds.

Once I run it, it has no problem at first.
However, after some time, like 30 minutes or 1 hour, the program hangs in the middle. The program doesn't print anything anymore.
I have to press enter so the program will continue printing again.

Has anybody experience this problem? How can I make my program run indefinitely without hanging? thanks!

Code:

```
while(true){
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now());
    System.Threading.Sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: i think it could be low memory issue please check with your available Ram.

Comment: I think it could be low memory issue please check with your available Ram.because it is used for temporary storage when you run your program its is being temporary loading in ram so that when this line execute continuously require more memory also use seconds in sleep method.

Comment: Depending on the properties of your console window, certain types of click on it make it think you want to select text, so the output gets paused. Can you confirm whether it is just pausing on its own, without any user interaction?

Comment: Looks like a memory issue. Suggest you to check TaskManager.

Comment: Pressing the Enter key does not solve memory issues or end a garbage collection.  It does complete a Console.Read/Line() call or a Edit > Mark session.  Console.Read blocking a Console.Write could happen in 4.5 RTM but that got fixed.  Press Alt+Space > Properties > Options, untick the "QuickEdit mode" checkbox to lower the odds that an accidental mouse click starts an mark session.  And do wonder a bit how this program could be useful to anybody.

Answer (score 2):

The `Sleep` argument is in milliseconds NOT seconds.  Try changing it to `10 * 1000`.

The pause after 30 mins or 1 hour could be to due to Garbage Collection.  Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/ for possible work arounds.

Comment: Isn't the garbage collection in C# automatic? And I have big memory in our server, 16GB, so the memory should not be an issue, right?